# How to Create Sections/Panels in WinUI3 in a Page

Tags: c#, winui-3

I'm very new to WinUI, with some experience with WinForms. I was wondering what elements are used to create different sections in a page (such as the multiple examples per page seen in WinUI-3), with the section headers and curved boxes/frames/panels.

Any advice the right direction would be very helpful. Thanks.

[image: WinUI-3 Sections]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [SettingsCard](https://toolkitlabs.dev/) from the **CommunityToolkit Labs**.

If you want to implement it yourself, this is some code that I'm implementing in my library **AK.Toolkit**. (not finished yet...)
I hope this puts you in a good direction.

**HeaderedPanel.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;

namespace HeaderedPanels;

[ContentProperty(Name = "Content")]
public sealed class HeaderedPanel : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Header),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(HeaderedPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Content),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(HeaderedPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentMarginProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ContentMargin),
        typeof(Thickness),
        typeof(HeaderedPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderMarginProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(HeaderMargin),
        typeof(Thickness),
        typeof(HeaderedPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public HeaderedPanel()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(HeaderedPanel);
    }

    public Thickness ContentMargin
    {
        get => (Thickness)GetValue(ContentMarginProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContentMarginProperty, value);
    }

    public Thickness HeaderMargin
    {
        get => (Thickness)GetValue(HeaderMarginProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderMarginProperty, value);
    }

    public object Header
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
    }

    public object Content
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(ContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HeaderedPanels">

    <Thickness x:Key="HeaderedPanelHeaderMargin">5,10,10,0</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="HeaderedPanelContentMargin">10,10,10,10</Thickness>
    <CornerRadius x:Key="HeaderedPanelCornerRadius">5</CornerRadius>
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="HeaderedPanelBrush"
        Color="{StaticResource SolidBackgroundFillColorBase}" />

    <Style TargetType="local:HeaderedPanel">
        <Setter Property="HeaderMargin" Value="{StaticResource HeaderedPanelHeaderMargin}" />
        <Setter Property="ContentMargin" Value="{StaticResource HeaderedPanelContentMargin}" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{StaticResource HeaderedPanelCornerRadius}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HeaderedPanelBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:HeaderedPanel">
                    <Grid
                        RowDefinitions="Auto,*"
                        RowSpacing="0">
                        <ContentControl
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding HeaderMargin}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                        <Border
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Margin="0"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                            <ContentControl
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding ContentMargin}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And use it like this:

```xml
<local:HeaderedPanel>
    <local:HeaderedPanel.Header>
        <TextBlock
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Text="Awesome Header" />
    </local:HeaderedPanel.Header>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Enter your lucky number and click the button." />
        <TextBox />
        <Button Content="Button" />
    </StackPanel>
</local:HeaderedPanel>
```